# How to cast pointer to unnamed struct pointer?

Tags: c++

I had this struct the other day:

```
struct foo_t {
  char a, b, c;
} *foo = (foo_t*)untyped_memory;
```

…but having a named type for it was excessive. However, its unnamed form:

```
struct {
  char a, b, c;
} *bar = untyped_memory;
```

...did not compile because of pointer types being incompatible.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: How is naming a type "excessive"? Are you on a really tight character budget?

Comment: Why not use a tuple?

Comment: @molbdnilo name clashes, mostly

Comment: @Andreas that is what namespaces are meant for

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have access to C++11 or above then you can use [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) i.e.

```
struct {
  char a, b, c;
} *bar = (decltype(bar))untyped_memory;
```